# How do you log messages from all channels with a guild id? Discord.js

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I have been working on a channel logger that logs all the messages from within a channel into another discord server.

Now that I got the guild id idea to log all the messages from the discord server with the guild id I need some help writing the code for it.

Everything I tried hasn't worked and I need to figure out how to fetchMessages from the guild id.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, please explain more on what you are trying to achieve and the things you've done so far with the code you've done. Then we can help you fix the code. This isn't a place to just ask for someone to write the whole code for you.

```
client.on(`message`, message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return; // If the message is by a bot return.
    if (!message.guild) return; // If the message isn't in a guild return.
    if (message.guild) {
        const msgLog = `[MESSAGE] [${message.guild.name}] [#${message.channel.name}] ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}: ${message.content}\n` // You can change this to whatever you want.
        client.channels.get(`CHANNEL ID`).send(msgLog); // Replace CHANNEL ID with the channel ID you want the logs to go to.
        return;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Acctually you don't need guild id if it is private bot, in my situation, this is code from my private bot.

```
bot.on('message',(message) => {
    // EVERY MESSAGE LOGGED
    if(message.author.bot) return;
        let botMessageLog = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(`Message Logging`, bot.user.avatarURL())
        .setDescription(`**${message.author.toString()}** said: **${message.content}** in channel **${message.channel.toString()}**`)
        .setFooter(`Text for footer`, bot.user.avatarURL())
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor("FF0000");
        bot.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL ID").send(botMessageLog)
});
```

Try this, I hope I helped you.